# Where can I find IRQF_NODELAY flag in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, rtos

I got an error when I built a device driver with IRQF_NODELAY in Linux 3.0.9. 
And I found that IRQF_NODELAY was disappeared since somewhere after 2.6.x.
For the realtime job, I need an ISR that is not working as a thread.
Because I patched vanilla kernel with RT-Linux, the default ISR mode is not a real ISR but a thread.

Is IRQF_NODELAY deprecated? Can I use some flag equivalent to IRQF_NODELAY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IRQ_NODELAY was replaced by IRQF_NO_THREAD. It works fine, I have used it for one project. You can pass it as third argument in the request_irq function.

Comment: I'm unsure why this answer keeps getting deleted by moderators.  It appears to be an answer to the question, which specifically asks for an equivalent flag.  I don't know about the technical merits, but that's a job for voting, not moderator action.